# Updating a property value when changing features with a Wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an installer authored in Wix.  The installer UI allows the user to select some settings.  For example there is a checkbox to enable https for the web services.  The values of these settings are stored in the windows registry using Rob Mensching's ["Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern).  They update config files using the WixUtilExtension XmlFile.  Installing the application the first time works fine.

When the user runs the installer again (when the application is already installed) they are given the option of changing features via the MaintenanceTypeDlg.  The user can add or remove features in the CustomizeDlg.  Then the installer wizard allows the user to change settings (e.g. https web services).   Feature changes work fine, but when the user changes a setting it is ignored (the config file and registry key is not updated).  Presumably because the config file and registry key are already installed.

How can I get the installer to make setting changes (update config files and registry keys) when making feature changes?  Or is this not the right thing to do with windows installer?

Comment: Create a verbose msi log file during maintenance and it should tell you the state and scheduled action of files, components, and features.

Comment: Good idea.  The log file confirms that the registry values are not written to the registry during the maintenance install (the WriteRegistryValues action does nothing).  So is it possible to get the installer to rewrite registry values during a maintenance install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XmlFile WixUtilExtension will only run in two scenarios.  If the component it belongs to is being installed the xml entry will get modified, and when the component is being uninstalled the xml entry the modification will get removed.

During a maintenance installation, the xml entry is not touched because the component most likely has the properties State: Installed, Request: Local, and so Action: Null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367858.aspx

The fix is "to set REINSTALL" as mentioned here:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/use-XmlFile-XmlConfig-in-maintenance-mode-td5520598.html

Try setting the property REINSTALL=ALL using the command line to see if that works.
If so, then I'm thinking it can be set dynamically if the user chooses to perform a maintenance installation.

Comment: Yes! Setting the REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE property is the key.  Thank you Rami.

Comment: It took me a little while to find the right way to do it (setting REINSTALL from the command line means the UI does not display the MaintenanceTypeDlg so the user can't choose "Change").  I ended up taking the VerifyReadyDlg from Wix source and making a few modifications.  I inserted the following 2 child elements in the change pushbutton controls:  
    <Publish Event="ReinstallMode" Value="amu"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
    <Publish Event="Reinstall" Value="Server"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>

Comment: I then used the new version of the VerifyReadyDlg in the UI instead of the original.

The "Server" value of the REINSTALL property is the id of the feature that contains the registry keys and the config file. So whenever the user chooses to change the application, the Server feature is always reinstalled, ensuring that any new property values changed on the UI dialogs are persisted to the registry and the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the property's value in a registry key and recall it during a maintenance install.

```
<Property Id="MyProperty">
  <RegistrySearch
    Id="MyProperty"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="Software\Manufacturer\Product"
    Name="MyProperty"
    Type="raw" />
</Property>

<Component Id="MyProperty">
  <RegistryValue
    Id="MyProperty"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Manufacturer\Product"
    Name="MyProperty"
    Type="string"
    Value="[MYPROPERTY]"
    KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

Comment: I have tried this.  The value of "MyProperty" is correctly recalled from the registry when running a maintenance install.  However, if you try changing its value during the maintenance install, the new value is not written to the registry.